# How to build an app with iOs6 features with xcode < 4.5?

Tags: build, compilation, conditional-statements, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

I'm working on the future version of my app and want to integrate some iOs6 new classes like UIRefreshControl. I know I can't submit my app with xcode 4.5 yet. So I go back to an xcode < 4.5 and build, but I've got errors because it doesn't know that class.

How can I put conditions in my code in order to by pass building errors and get my code well conditionned for iOs < 6 and  iOs >= 6.

I tried several things like :

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_6_0
```

or

```
#ifdef _USE_OS_6_OR_LATER
```

But they don't work... I still get errors.

Comment: you can submit with xcode 4.5 as of yesterday. Gold Master Version is able to submit an app

Comment: @jussi - why isn't that an answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can submit with xcode 4.5 as of yesterday. Gold Master Version is able to submit an app

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.